Why don't satellites use distance covered to achieve 100% accuracy in time sync?
Current satellites experience an error of 38 micro seconds per day. But can be 100% accurate by using Earth as a natural clock, where:
For every 8.26 kms covered = 1 second(considering earth's rotation)
Total orbital circuit = Complete time cycle
Instead of relying on atomic clocks which give errors due to various forces, simply use Earth's orbital path as a timing mechanism.
Distance Measurement Method:

Use latitude and longitude coordinates
Track total distance traveled
Measure against Earth's orbital circumference
Velocity variations don't matter - only total distance counts

If any external factor affects the measurement, just reset the clock once a year - much better than daily corrections.
Fundamentally, Earth itself becomes the clock. Just follow the "ticking hand" around the planet, where the complete orbit represents one perfect time cycle.
Simple. Precise. 100% Accurate.

This seems to be a rewrite of the question that you posted earlier in Astronomy which was then migrated here. You should edit that question with your changes instead of creating a new question since it seems to be the same question.

@StevePemberton I didn't know i can change i deleted it. But can you provide info on this approach? Is it possible/practical?

At the bottom of your post there is a line that says Share Edit Follow etc. If you click Edit you can edit your question. However if someone has already posted an answer do not make any substantial changes that would invalidate their answer. In those cases it's better to add an addendum or changes with a heading "Edit" or "Update" or similar, leaving the original text in place. But for just spelling or grammar, or to add additional points or elaborations, you can just go in and edit it.  After doing this an "Edited" indicator will appear, which anyone can click on to see what you changed.

38 microseconds is the relativistic error, which is easily adjusted for. That doesn't affect the essence of your question about using ground tracking for timing, I'm just pointing it out.

the implication that you can measure the position (or distance covered) with 100% accuracy, while that wasn't possible with time, is fallacious

One of the reasons the second is based on hyperfine transitions of cesium is because the rotation and orbit of the Earth isn't regular enough for consistent calibration at the desired precision.

If the Earth's orbit was so stable as you assume, IERS would be out of business. Have a look at these plots to get an idea.

@Ludo, also this plot, which shows DUT1 on the vertical axis and time (year) on the horizontal axis. The big vertical jumps in the plot are when leap seconds were added to UTC. It's kinda random.

You are wrong, satellite orbits are not at all a perfect circle and the low orbit cycle time is not constant.

Let's suppose we have a ground station directly under your satellite's track. You look precisely down (ignoring the problem of how to determine what "precisely down" means) and reset your clock based on a calculated value every time you go over the ground station.
The biggest problem is that no orbit is perfect and unchanging. Light pressure and solar wind create forces on the satellite, not to mention the tidal forces from the moon and other bodies. These forces may not be large, but if you were trying to measure your position down to microsecond precision, they'll mess with your calculation.
For satellites in low-earth orbit, the atmosphere itself is a problem, because there's a certain amount of drag even in what is functionally a vacuum, and it varies depending on season and time of day. The ISS famously loses about two kilometers of altitude every year and has to reboost from time to time to maintain its altitude, and unmanned satellites in LEO have similar requirements to a greater or lesser extent. In addition, the orbit gets perturbed in tiny amounts by the varying density of our planet as masses sweep by underneath. The earth's gravity field is a mass of "anomalies" caused by mountain ranges, ocean trenches, and so on. In a way, an object in LEO is less an ice skater gliding smoothly across a rink than a truck bouncing down a dirt road.
Geostationary is hardly any better. That far out, the atmosphere and gravity anomalies aren't as big a problem, but the moon's impact is much higher, and it's not just tides. The sun and moon produce a twisting force that tries to change a satellite's inclination over time.
Station-keeping is an active process for a satellite that requires fuel and power. Lack of fuel is usually what determines end-of-life for a satellite, as without it they'll drift further and further from their intended location and eventually become unusable, or potentially cause a collision. Most satellites use the last of their fuel to either intentionally deorbit or, for geostationary satellites, boost up into a 'graveyard orbit' where they'll be out of the way of active satellites and free up their valuable parking space in GEO. (GEO is too high to easily deorbit from, so pushing into a slightly higher orbit is the better option for getting out of the way.)
Needless to say, if you have to use thrusters to station-keep, the orbit isn't perfect enough to use for microsecond time-keeping. If you need to correct the time using some kind of ground-based signal to account for orbital imperfections, well, then you're back to just using a ground based clock for time correction. At that point, you might as well forget the orbit tracking part and just do a scheduled sync, which is what we already do.

Yes you're right but these can be addressed with once in a month resets. And some with prior calculations Right? Like much better than daily reset for atomic clocks.

If you need a ground-based clock to keep your timing consistent, then you just use the ground-based clock and forget having a secondary process.  Why would it be better to get a ground-based signal once a month instead of daily? What's the benefit?

@DarthPseudonym, mention that in the answer. If anything that’s as good a part of the answer as the rest of it.

Agreed; I've been running a program that that retrieves and records ISS pass predictions for the next week from Heavens Above every 24 hours, for more than a decade now. These predictions change every day, though usually by about 1-2 seconds. That said, occasionally the predicted times change by 10 seconds or more.

@notovny Interesting! I'm guessing the large changes happen when they've just done a reboost so the orbit is suddenly longer?

What are you doing that requires you set up this highly-convoluted system to correct for only 38 microseconds a day? An error of one part in around 2,270,000,000 is really low - it would take a very very long time for that to ever be noticeable by mere humans. We can just correct for it daily, anyway, with a few operations on a computer system that take a few milliseconds at most each time you turn it on.
Anyways, you cannot get “100%” accurate. Satellites are constantly accelerated because of atmospheric drag. It is, of course, impossible to synchronize two clocks that are not both unaccelerated, due to relativistic effects.

38 microseconds is 11km difference. That's significant. Okay forget about earth now consider jupiter or heavy gravity planets. The error would be way too much. This method is universal for every planet measures time more accurately than atomic clocks. When i said it's 100% perfect is considering other factors negligible as they only like once a month. Once a month reset is far far better than daily reset

@Cashify you make heavy assumptions regarding the accuracy of your proposed method. Also, in this comment you equate 38 microseconds to 11 km, but you also say “8.26 kilometers covered = 1 second” in your question. With the latter number, 38 microseconds is about 32 centimeters, or about 1 foot.

"Once a month reset is far far better than daily reset" - why? Additional resets have a negligible cost once you have a system that can perform resets.
